# formatting json documents

Tags: .net, json, formatting

. I am building an utility to manage mongo database. I am using visual studio 2010 and framework 4.0. Now, when display documents , they are not formatted thus not understandable. I just want to beautify it with indentations and line breaks without serializing it; since I am not working with objects. I just got document and I want to format them. For this , I have tried JsonPrettyPrinter.dll but it uses framework 3.5.  I have json.net but I dont know how to use it for formatting. Please tell me the way of doing it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're using JSON.NET, you can use this code to format (pretty-print) the JSON document:

```
string json = "...";
JToken jt = JToken.Parse(json);
string formatted = jt.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: Thank you. . I will try and let you know

Comment: I have tried but it is giving the following exception.                                                        Error parsing positive infinity value. Path 'address[0].values[0]', line 1, position 101.

Comment: One more thing , the json contains boolean, datetime etc. Now please let me know the answer

Answer (score 2):

If it's an option, both Chrome and Firefox have a useful plugin called JSONView which do what you want.

- [JSONView for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jsonview/)
- [JSONView for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc)